# How to register a buttonhandler (nested class)

Tags: java, javafx, eventhandler

I am trying to register my button, but I don't know how to do that, I have created a nested class ButtonHandler implementing EventHandler to define its action.

I've tried the code musicRecord.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler()); , and it doesnt seem to work, I want to register the ButtonHandler to musicRecord.

```
    musicRecord = new Button("Create a Music Record");
private class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Music m1 = new Music();
        m1.setTitle(titleField.getText());
        m1.setYear(Integer.parseInt(yearField.getText()));
        m1.setDescription(descField.getText());
        musicDisplay.appendText(m1.toString());
        musicList.add(m1);
}
```

I expect the button to carry out the event actions when clicked.

Comment: Can you provide more details about "it doesnt seem to work".

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: assuming this is about javafx, so removing the javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your error when you say "doesnt work". The below is simple quick working demo. You figure out where you going wrong.

Note: If the sole purpose of inner class is to define the handle() method, then you can do it with lambda.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomHandlerDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Check");
        button.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler());

        // You can do it like this as well
        /*
        button.setOnAction(e->{
            System.out.println("Clicked 2");
        });
        */

        root.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Clicked 1");
        }
    }

}
```